# Load JSON file into JSON-Store is not working

Tags: json, extjs, jsonstore

below you can see my Login functionality, which actually is working. But it does not load the provided json file by the server into JSON Store.

"console.log("Store before load",UserStore)" and "console.log("Store after load",UserStore)" shows exactly the same message, so i guess "UserStore.load(jsonRes)" is not working at all. I also tried "UserStore.loadData(jsonRes)" and "UserStore.loadRawData(jsonRes)" which both work neither (Error: Uncaught TypeError: Object[object Object] has no method 'loadDataRaw').
Could you please explain me how to fix that issue? Thanks a lot.

```
Ext.util.JSONP.request({

url: 'http://127.0.0.1:4712/talentcommunity/getuserinfo',

headers: { 
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded ; charset=utf-8'
},

method: 'post',

params: {
    user:data1,
    pw:data2
},

callbackName: 'myCallback',

success: function (response) {

    var loginResponse = response;
    if (loginResponse.msg == "OK") {
        var UserStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'Sabine.model.user',
            data: response.user
        });
        me.signInSuccess();
    }
    else{
        loginView.showSignInFailedMessage('token null.');   
    } 

},
```

The Json file provided look like this:

```
{msg: "OK", user: Object}
```

'user' itself looks like this:     `{"token":"ee80d56688fb7d3a8bcf5939fc9cbcf1","title":"","login":"bmuster","facebookId":"","firstName":"Bertha","lastName":"Muster","nationality":"GM","birthDay":"12/09/82","phone":"+4989111111","mobile":"+4918111111","street":"Musterstra\ufffde 11","city":"Musterstadt","zipCode":"66666","willingToTravel":"","pictureUrl":"","eMail":"bmuster@example.com","publicList":[]}`

My Store is defined as follows:

```
Ext.define('Sabine.store.MyJsonPStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'Sabine.model.user'
],

config: {
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    clearOnPageLoad: false,
    model: 'Sabine.model.user',
    storeId: 'myStore'
}
});
```

The corresponding model:

```
Ext.define('Sabine.model.user', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'token',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'title'
        },
        {
            name: 'login'
        },
        {
            name: 'facebookId'
        },
        {
            name: 'firstName',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'lastName',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'nationality',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'birthDay',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'phone'
        },
        {
            name: 'mobile'
        },
        {
            name: 'street'
        },
        {
            name: 'city',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'zipCode',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'willingToTravel'
        },
        {
            name: 'pictureUrl'
        },
        {
            name: 'eMail'
        },
        {
            name: 'publicList'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

Example of a View:

```
Ext.define('Sabine.view.MeinAccount', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias: 'widget.accview',
    config: {
        maxHeight: 480,
        maxWidth: 320,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        height: 430,
        maxHeight: 480,
        items: [
            {
            xtype: 'list',
            title: 'Allgemein',
            iconCls: 'home',
            modal: false,
            deferEmptyText: false,
            itemTpl: [
                '<table border = "0">',
                '<tr>',
                ' <td>Firstname</td>',
                ' <td>{firstName}</td>',
                ' <td>Last<name/td>',
                ' <td>{lastName}</td>',
                '</tr>',
                '<tr>',
                ' <td>Nationality</td>',
                ' <td>{nationality}</td>',
                '</tr>',
                '</table>'
            ],
            store: 'Sabine.store.UserStore'
     },
```

Comment: Please post the definition of your store.

Comment: Hey, i edited my question above. Now you can see the store's defintion.

Comment: I forgot to ask, please post the definition of `Sabine.model.user` too, and the version of Ext JS you are using. Thanks.

Comment: My Question now contains the Model too,.. I'm using Secha Touch 2.0.1.1 , does that information help you?

Comment: Look at what you're doing. The response is already a json object. Then you're converting it to a string and then passing to `load`. Secondly, where is `user` in your response? None of the keys in what you posted match that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of thoughts about your problem:

- you have a field `publicList` that is not declared in your model
- `store.load` does not accept an instance of a model, on the contrary - it loads your local store with the data from the server
- `store.loadData` or `store.loadRawData` is your way to go, however the message you mention (Uncaught TypeError: Object[object Object] has no method..) indicates that you haven't successfully retrieved an instance of store. In order to do so you should firstly instantiate the store, not just declare it; use `Ext.create` method for that
- if your `loginResponse.user` is already in JSON format, you shouldn't use `Ext.JSON.encode`

Comment: Thank you for you annotations. I think, I now have initiated the store by putting some code within the success function. I edited my question so you can see the new code. It also loads data into that store. In the next step I like to put the data to the speficic views of the app, could you give me some hints how to handle that? I haven no idea how to access the store fromt different views. I also posted an example of a view into my question above.

Comment: @Daniel90 Glad to help. You should use the same store in your view, there you reference `Sabine.store.UserStore`, and the id of your store is `Sabine.store.MyJsonPStore`. Additionally, don't use HTML tags to render the grid, use instead Ext.grid.Panel and within items section enumerate the fields from your model as a property `dataIndex`. See http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel for further reading, there are great tutorials available as well.

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
success: function (response) {

    var loginResponse = response.responseText;
    ....
}
```

Comment: Hey there, thank you for your answer .. when i try "loginResponse = response.responseText;" it says loginResponse is undefined.

Comment: And if you provide a flag `success: true` in your json response ?

Comment: try to `console.log` your response variable.

Comment: console.log(response) => Object {msg: "OK", user: Object}             'user' itself looks like this: {"token":"ee80d56688fb7d3a8bcf5939fc9cbcf1",....,"city":"NewYork","zipCode":"66666",...}